# Update user edited Core Data database

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a general question about best practices for a `core data` scenario. I'm building an iOS app that has a seeded databased shipped with the app. The users can also add their own content to the database.

Later on, I will probably add additional content to the bundled seeded database or maybe even let the user buy additional content using IAP. But how do I best update the database with both new and updated seeded information without risking messing with the users own content?

I'm thinking of two scenarios:

1. Have some guid identifier for each row so that I can insert/update system data.
2. Have two databases, on for seeded data and one for user created data. How ever, this will make queries and view controllers more complex.

Are there any best practices for these kind of issues?

Answer (score 0):

Something you could do is create 1 database that is bundled with the app and have another copy of the database on a web server (like MySQL).  Setup your app to check for new data every week or so and save the new and updated data from the web server into Core Data.

This allows users to add their own content and update the database with both new and updated seeded information without the risk of messing with users own content.

It would also provide a “backup” of user data stored remotely within the MySQL database if you wanted to go that route as well.